# Are these simple water shut-off valves reversible?

Tags: plumbing, shower, valve

I bought a [valve](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D8VWZGH) for which the seller has posted a picture that shows that the male side of the valve goes into shower hose and the female side of the valve goes into shower handle:

[image]

However, I am questioning if that picture is correct, because the filter net that came with the valve can be put only on valve's female side:

[image]

And best to my knowledge, these filter nets are there with purpose to stop debris from entering valve shutoff mechanism that could cause fail-open situation. Which clearly is not the case here.

**So my question is - Is the picture posted by seller incorrect? Can I install the valve the way I think is correct instead by using a wall mount shower head that has the opposite-gender thread compared to a handheld shower head?:**

[image]

Comment: the mesh is not for the protection of the valve ... that type of valve is very difficult to make it fail open

Comment: @jsotola I imagine that if pieces of improperly installed teflon tape would get there then it could cause the valve to fail in open state and leak water. Anyway, what do you think about direction of the valve - is it reversible?

Comment: jsotola is correct. i see no point in reversing it but with enough fittings ( and money ) you could do it. *I see no point in having the filter in the valve in the first place* as the shower head will have its own filters. I would remove the filter and install it in the direction it was designed to be and not spend the money on extra fittings. **Why complicate things needlessly?** Do not improperly install Teflon tape.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I actually MUST use male-to-male adapter anyway because I want to use wall mounted shower head. Wall mounted shower heads are different because they have female thread. This shower head will be used in a beauty salon hair wash sink and low profile is important to make it easier to wash hair and hold shower head at the same time. Can't use  shower head with a handle that has a male thread.

Comment: There is a whole industry of products made for beauty salon sinks and the accompanying hair washing spray heads.  Why cant you use a product designed for the task?   https://www.amazon.com/Salon-Shampoo-Equipment-Chrome-Sprayer/dp/B01N9UVPLL/ref=sr_1_26?keywords=salon+sink+sprayer&qid=1570946924&sr=8-26

Comment: @AlaskaMan The reason is that I need a low profile shower head with a built-in and, most importantly, reliable water shut off valve, because I recently switched to a thermostatic water mixer that does not have a built in shut off valve and sits in hard to access place. So, my current plan is to keep hose pressurized at all times and have a valve next to shower head for easy operation. Nevertheless, the link you sent looks promising because this shower head has a button on it which I presume is shut off valve. Most salon shower heads I could find did not have build shut off valves.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Actually, by looking at salon shampoo shower heads that look exactly the same as the one you sent to me it seems that button actually allows to chose between more and less water. Instead of allowing to shut off water flow completely. Can you suggest what are the keywords I need to use to find a similar shower head, but that would allow me to shut off water completely with a built-in button? Thanks a lot for your help!